# For which $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, $\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\cdots,\beta^{k-1}\}$ form a basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ be a finite field. For which $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, $\mathcal{B}_{\beta}:=\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\cdots,\beta^{k-1}\}$ form a $\mathbb{F}_p$-basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$? Indeed, $\mathcal{B}_{\beta}$ is a basis when $\beta$ is a primitive element (sufficient condition). But is there a neat necessary-and-sufficient condition on such $\beta$? Any reference, idea, or comment will be very helpful.

Comment: This holds iff $\mathbb F_{p^k}=\mathbb F_p[\beta]$

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for? One can of course write down a list of more or less obvious conditions, like $k = min\{n | \beta^{p^n} = \beta\}$ but they might be completely uninteresting to you...

Comment: Drawing on @Wojowu's comment, the set of $\beta$ satisfying his identity is the complement of all proper subfields $\mathbb{F}_{p^i} \subsetneq \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, each of which is an $\mathbb{F_p}$-linear subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ (since it has a basis). So we can describe the set of suitable $\beta$ as the complement of a union of vector subspaces, which depending on how you choose your basis may give a more or less elegant characterization.

Comment: It holds iff $\beta\notin\bigcup_{\ell|k}\mathbb{F}_{p^\ell}$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $\beta$ must have minimum polynomial of degree $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, and this minimum polynomial is necessarily irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x].$  Since all fields of cardinality $p^{k}$ are isomorphic, you are essentially asking for the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $k$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$- to be explicit, if there are $m(k)$ such irreducible polynomials of degree $k$, then there are $km(k)$ elements $\beta$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k}}$ with the properties you want. All this is fairly standard finite field theory. There are well known recursive formulae for the numbers $m(k)$. Note that any element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k}}$ has minimum polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ of degree $d$ dividing $k$, so to count the elements $\beta$ you want, you need to exclude those elements $\alpha$ whose minimum polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ has degree a proper divisor of $k$.